# How To Show / Close Loading Form In Windows Applications of .Net CF 3.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework

I Create a Smart Device Application (.Net CF 3.5), and Create a Loading Form and Call It *ModalLoadingUI*, this form must be shown when an Operation Is ongoing. the Source Code of this form is:

```
public partial class ModalLoadingUI : Form
{

    public Form BackgroundForm { get; set; }

    public ModalLoadingUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void ModalLoadingUI_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundForm != null) BackgroundForm.Enabled = true;
    }        
}
```

During an operation this form is shown, for example :

```
private void btnShowLoading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loading = new ModalLoadingUI { BackgroundForm = this };
    this.Enabled = false;
    loading.CenterForm();
    loading.Show();

    try
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        loading.Close();
    }
}
```

Can I show an Instance of `ModalLoadingUI` form with `ShowDialog()` Method Instead Of using `Show()` method ?  and After the operation is done and then Loading Close ? Due to the Codes after `ShowDialog()` method Will Not Run.

I know that I Can Show Loading by another Thread, With code like the following:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => new ModalLoadingUI().ShowDialog()));
```

But this is Not my desired code, Because I Want to Run CenterForm() method on the instance of `ModalLoadingUI` , and After the operation is done then Loading Must Be Closed.

How I Can Show / Close Loading Form (`ModalLoadingUI`) Based on the foregoing?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: There is a MSDN article on how two show/hide a splash screen (similar to your request): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446493.aspx. You MUST load the Form from within a separate thread or it will block your code. You can invoke a method inside the threaded Form to close it. I would not go with an anonymous Action but use a thread function code that you can control. What do you mean with 'Run CenterForm() method'. If this is a Windows Mobile device, all forms are fullscreen by default.

Comment: thank you josef, CenterForm() is an extension method for Form Data Type that center horizontally and vertically that form.

Comment: As said, on Windows Mobile (2003,5,6,embedded handheld 6.5) all forms are fullscreen and there is no need to center the form. On windows ce 5 devices, a form is not fullscreen by default and cntering a form makes sense.

Comment: In this case, the loading form may not be full screen

Comment: Again: on Windows Mobile all CF Forms are fullscreen except you compile against 'Windows CE' SDK.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` is a poor choice because the called Form gets its own message pump and effectively blocks the caller.

What you want is a UI element that covers probably a middle section and says "working"  and maybe some progress update.  The CF isn't the best suited for this, but it's definitely possible.  Here's how I'd attack this problem:

1. Create the "loading" form with no border, no control box, no minimize or maximize box.  This will allow it to not be only full-screen and you can position it.
2. Create the Loading form and show it in some "service" method that displays it with a call to `Show` and then waits for the caller to finish.  This is predicated on the caller immediately doing background processing - it can *not* be on the UI thread.

Here's some non-compiled pseudocode:

```
// this would go in some service-level class
public void ShowLoading(Func<bool> workToDo)
{
    using(var load = new LoadingForm())
    {
        var completed = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        new Thread(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    workToDo();
                }
                finally
                {
                    completed.Set();
                }
            });

        // show the loading form
        load.Show();

        // wait for the background worker
        while (!completed.WaitOne(100))
        {
            // just keep waiting
            // the timeout allows the UI to update
            // if you want to update the loading form with progress
            // or whatever, do that here
        }
    }
}
```

And the caller would look something like this:

```
void Foo()
{
    // this is the "entry point"
    ShowLoading(MyWorker);
}

bool MyWorker()
{
    // do your long-running stuff here
}
```

If you really want to get fancy you could screen capture before showing it, shade that, then draw your stuff on top of it making the "background form" look like it's disabled, but I'd certainly get the above working first - walk before you run.

Answer (score 0):

Pezman,

I've found a coupe of ways to do this without the aid of a third party tool (like [SlideUI](http://www.devslide.com/products/slideui)):

**Panel:**

I use a hidden panel on a form that I make visible.  If you need to disable the form while the panel runs, you can do that.  The drawback is that if you have multiple forms running processes, you'd have to make a hidden panel on each form.  Also, to make a border on the panel, you'd have to add this paint function:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    Dim CurPanel As Panel = CType(sender, Panel)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, CurPanel.Width - 1, CurPanel.Height - 1)
End Sub
```

**Form:**

You can use a form, assuming that the form you trigger the operation from has events.
Pro: A self-contained class can be called from anywhere
Con: No easy way to make it a smaller, centered window, must declare events, must use a form to control the operation update.

Here is one way to do it: let's assume Form1 triggers the operation, and Form2 is your status.

Form1 (owner of the process) would need an event function like so:

```
Public Event UpdateStatus(ByVal NewVal As String)
```

Then it would need to raise an event when something happens:

```
RaiseEvent UpdateStatus(NewValue)
```

Form2 (status update) would have to have a pointer to Form1. There are several ways to do this - you could assign at new or assign later among others:

```
    Private WithEvents _pMain As Main

    Public Sub New(ByRef pMain As Main)

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        _pMain = pMain
    End Sub

    Private Sub StatUpdate(ByVal Status As String) Handles _pMain.UpdateStatus
        Label1.Text = Status
    End Sub
```

Neither option gives you 100% of what you want, but perhaps one of solutions has a caveat that you can live with.